# C# LINQ search of list, similar to how a database works

Tags: c#, linq

I have never used LINQ before I have only heard of it and I believe this is what I am looking for. I was given a text file with english words matched to spanish words. I have to take an english input, for example the aunt and match it to the spanish value la tia. If I run through the text file and create an array or list of word objects that store a category, english word, and spanish word. How can I go about doing something like this for example in C# code.

Find spanishValue from WordList where englishValue is like aunt; This example needs to account for the fact they may omit the 'the' or incorrectly spell the english word. I could do something like this in a database but how so in code.

My List:

```
List<Word> Words = new List<Word>();
```

My Word.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TranslatorLibrary
{
    public class Word
    {
        public String English { get; set; }
        public String Spanish { get; set; }

        public CategoryEnumerator Category { get; set; }
        public Word(String en, String sp, CategoryEnumerator cat)
        {
            English = en;
            Spanish = sp;
            Category = cat;
        }

        public static CategoryEnumerator matchCategory(String obj)
        {
            switch (obj)
            {
                case "Family":
                    return CategoryEnumerator.Family;
                default:
                    return CategoryEnumerator.Family;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking... Input and expected output will be helpful. Also please provide what you have tried already - There are a lot of linq questions, great documentation and even the SO documentation on c# -> Linq

Comment: Show us the data structures you'll use to read this data into.  Without it we can't offer any kind of guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a lot more to translating that just pure words, so **my answer will not discuss semantics**. Pure replacement only.

I think you think you can use LINQ here because it looks like SQL queries only that in code and you have done this in SQL before, right?

Anyways, LINQ is not the answer. LINQ capabilities are far too extensive to explain in this stage. Try following a tutorial instead. Suffice it to say it's not what you need to use here.

There are a many ways to accomplish your task. Here are two that I can think of off the top of my head:

(These both assume you have already parsed the word definition text file and built a dictionary of words in memory or that you are able to query the file on demand)

1. Use a regular expression to find all the words, then loop through them and get the corresponding translation from the word dictionary, OR
2. Write a lexical analyzer to tokenize the text in question. You can then go through the tokens and translate them as necessary.

I would suggest number 2, simply because it's something you can build upon if you wish to consider other things like semantics at some point.

The way a lexical analyzer works is that it will go through the text to translate and it will parse it, creating tokens for entities it recognizes. You can then go through these tokens and if you recognize it as a "word", you can query your dictionary and find the corresponding translation.

(this is how compilers work by the way)

Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

I am sure there are other ways. This is just a quick answer.

Comment: I know this is outside the scope of the current question now, but I am having a code problem that doesn't make sense to me I have never seen before. I have two text blocks the english text block on text changing sends the text into the dictionary and tries to find a match if not returns blank if finds a match return the word. Everything is fine until I find a match the debugger crashes and I get a warning saying that my applications debugger has an unhandled error.

Comment: I just changed how my application handles the translating never mind.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are looking for `.ToDictionary()` method.

If you have a list of object `string english, string spanish` elements you should make it `yourList.ToDictionary(p => english, p => spanish)` and this will make you able to type `resultDict['the Aunt']` and give you `la tia`.